# C++ Overloading operator<< outputs address

Tags: c++, overloading

So in my program I have some classes - Button, Window and WindowButton. Button consists only of text, Window - of a button and coordinates(x,y), and WindowButton consists of a Window.
In WindowButton, I have overloaded the << operator like this:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, WindowButton& ref)
{
    ref.print();
    return out;
}
```

Where the print function looks like:

```
void WindowButton::print()
{
    theWindow->print();
}
```

And the window print function, in window class:

```
void Window::print()
{
    char* buttonText = button->getText();
    char* theText = new char[strlen(buttonText)+1];
    strcpy(theText, buttonText);
    cout << endl << "Window with coordinates (" << this->coord.x << "," << this->coord.y << ") , and button text \"" << theText << "\"" << endl;
}
```

In main:

```
WindowButton *test = new WindowButton();
cout << endl << test;
test->print();
```

The last line provides the right output, but the second line provides just a memory adress. What am I doing wrong? Everything should be working fine, because the test->print(); works fine.

Comment: Side note:  In `Window::print`, there's no need to copy text into a buffer before printing it.  Just use `cout << button->getText()`.  You've actually got a memory leak as it is - you allocate a new buffer every time the function's called, and then it never gets freed.

Comment: @JonathanSeng say every thing but one question, why you dynamically allocate a memory copy button name to it, print it and then throw it away. you want to consume all memory of the system?? use the original buffer for printing to avoid performance and memory usage or at least delete dynamically allocated memory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing a pointer to operator<< which expects a &.

```
cout << endl << *test;
```

You might also make it:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const WindowButton& ref){
```

Which assumes print doesn't actually modify.

But, the bigger question is why are you using the `cout` ostream to trigger printing to `theWindow` -- these appear to be (though aren't) logically disconnected processes.  You could pass the given stream into Window::print:

```
void Window::print(ostream& stream) {
```

and use that stream in place of `cout`.  This avoids hard-coding `cout` into `Window::print()`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pointer, so you'll need to dereference it for the operator to work:

```
cout << endl << *test;
```

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
cout << endl << test;
```

prints a pointer to `WindowButton`, and there is an `ostream& operator<<` specialization for pointers, which prints the address. You can try de-referencing the pointer:

```
cout << endl << (*test);
```

As an aside, there is little point in overloading the `ostream& operator<<` in a way that eventually just prints to `std::cout`. The point of such an operator is that you can stream to *any* `ostream`, not just `cout`. You could fix this by modifying your `print` functions to take an `ostream` by reference, and modify it:

```
void WindowButton::print(std::ostream& out) const {
  theWindow->print(out);
}
```

and

```
void Window::print(ostream& out) const {
  // stuff
  out << "Window with coordinates (" << this->coord.x << "," << this->coord.y << ") , and button text \"" << theText << "\"" << endl;
}
```

and finally

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const WindowButton& ref){
  ref.print(out);
  return out;
}
```